# Why do .NET command arguments increase Docker image sizes

Tags: .net, dockerfile, .net-6.0

### Background

I am using Docker to create an image of a .NET-6.0 application. While trying to optimise my build times, I experimented with different build steps and `dotnet` command arguments. After a few iterations, I noticed that my created image size gets a lot bigger depending on the commands and command arguments used.

### Scenarios

There are three scenarios in which the image sizes differed.
Each of the scenarios make use of the following dockerfile and simply replace the `<SCENARIO>` section with the relevant scenario code.

```
# Setup the dotnet environment
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0-bullseye-slim AS environment

# Include code
COPY src /app/src

# Include tests
COPY tests /app/tests

# Specify the path in the directory to the testing secret
WORKDIR /app/tests
<SCENARIO>
```

#### Scenario A

A direct testing step.

```
dotnet test -c Release
```

#### Scenario B

A restore step is followed by a test step that disables restores.

```
dotnet restore --no-cache
dotnet test -c Release --no-restore
```

#### Scenario C

A build step is followed by the tests without building again.

```
dotnet build -c Release
dotnet test -c Release --no-build
```

#### Results

The results of the different scenarios are compared below.

| Scenario | Image size |
| --- | --- |
| A | 745.32 MB |
| B | 2.39 GB |
| C | 3.09 GB |

### Question

Is there a simple explanation as to why the image sizes increase in the different scenarios?

Comment: Adding your docker file would be useful, I think.

Comment: Added dockerfile as suggested

Comment: I tried this on my own test project and I don't get the results that you see. Scenarios A and C have the same size for me. And Scenario B is actually less than the other two. Is your .dockerignore file configured properly to ensure you're not copying stuff from the build context that you don't want, like a bin an obj directory?

Comment: One way to investigate the differences between the built images is to use a tool like dive: https://github.com/wagoodman/dive. Launch dive for each of the images and then navigate the directory structure to determine what's causing the differences amongst them.